# RLS Algorithm Convergence

Tags: estimation, kalman-filters, adaptive-filters

I am looking for some help to understand the concept how RLS converges? If possible to present it graphically that would be best. It is very easy to understand the understanding of convergence in case of LMS Algorithm but i am not being able to graphically visualize how its happening in case of RLS. How the cost function surface is being formed combining all previous weighted error? and How the weights are approaching towards optimum value on that surface?